# Create SOAP webservice(wsdl) client in c#

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

I have a soap based web service which has wsdl. and I have to create a windows form application client. can someone give me a small basic client?

Tips: that small web service has only a method named "

> CALL(id,name,address)

Comment: right click your project and select 'add a web reference'. [here's a tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having Drew's method in mind,

1. Right click on the project and select "add a service reference' and click "Advanced.." in add service reference dialog box. Then click "Add web reference" in add service reference dialog box. Input your webservice address in the address bar and click go. then rename your web reference name and click add reference.

(for ws security)
2.Go to the Reference.cs and change `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol` to  `Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesClientProtocol` (You might have to add service2 by nuget)

3. Before calling your webservice, add this.

UsernameToken token = new UsernameToken("", "", PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
yourProxy.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);